# MAUI Android Animation suddenly instantaneous on local device

Tags: android, animation, maui

On my local device, all my animations in all my MAUI Apps suddenly became instantaneous, I have no idea why. Everything was fine a couple of days ago.

The only thing I can think of is that I tried yesterday to play with the Particle.Maui nugget which didn't work at first because I missed adding a .UseSkiaSharp() in the MauiProgram.cs. I had some weird messages from Visual Studio telling me that there was an issue with "Just My Code".

A simple animation does not even work : if I create a new Maui .NET 7 project and in the code of the dummy button add this code (the kind of code I used a lot for my buttons before) :

```
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Animation
        new Animation {
            { 0, 1, new Animation (v => CounterBtn.Scale   = v, 1.0, 5.0) }
        }.Commit(this, "TapScale", length: 300, easing: Easing.CubicOut);
    }
```

On Window, it's smooth as expected, yielding the expected result. On my local Android device, however, the 5 scale value is applied to full extend instantaneously. I tried with another animation type, for instance, the opacity, and the behaviour is the same : no animation, it just jumps to the final result.

This impacts all my applications I developed, even existing ones that were not deployed again since I spotted the issue.

I just tried with an Android Emulator with the same level as my local device (Android 13 - API33), everything's fine, so it seems it is linked specifically to my device.

Is there a developper settings I played with that I cannot recall which magically stops the animation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have disabled animations in the developer options of your Android device?
Another option is that battery saver is enabled, that can also disable animations.

Comment: Well, I searched for such one but didn't find any. I may have skipped one as there is a bunch of options, but still, I don't recall having tempered with developper options. I tried opting out of developper mode on my device then back in again (pressed 7 times the build number) to no avail...

Comment: Are you on battery saver ? That could also disable all animations.

Comment: This was indeed the case, I had no clue the battery saver mode disabled the animation. ! Feel free to post an anwser, @peterdk, so I'll mark it as answered :)

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my phone was on battery saving mode which disables animations.
Exiting Battery Saving Mode did the trick.